# Check if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

I am trying to an app on Angular 5 to run a third party API which has Access-Control-Allow-Origin disabled. I have installed in my chrome an extension which allows it. How do I find out if its enabled in the browser so that I can do something else? I want to do something like.

```
if(Access-Control-Allow-Origin == enabled){
// do this
}}
else{
//do that 
}
```

Comment: send the request. if it works, it works. if it doesn't, it doesn't.

Comment: An extension breaking the same origin policy ? **Don't do that.** You obviously don't know what you're doing. That's like removing the door on your new house because you're too lazy to look for your keys.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you use jQuery to do that.

```
$.ajax("Put a file name here you are trying to get")
    .fail(function(d) {
        if (d.status != "200" || d.statusText == "error") {
            // do stuff (this dosent always work)
        }
    })
```